# flux through this region [paraboloid+ellipsoid]

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I have this region :

$D=\{x\ge y^2+z^2,x^2+2y^2+2z^2\le 3\}$

with vector field : $F=(xy^2,xz^2,yx^2)$

**Thought process** :

So It's a paraboloid and an ellipsoid. I need to calculate the flux outgoing this surface. I can use the divergence theorem : $\mathrm{div}(F)=y^2$

Using cylindrical coordinates:

$$\begin{cases}
x=x\\
y=r\sin\theta\\
z=r\cos\theta
\end{cases}
$$

In order to find the radius $r$ I can check the intersection on x of those two surfaces (plugging it back into the paraboloid gives me the radius):

$$\begin{cases}
x^2+2(y^2+z^2)= 3\\
x=y^2+z^2
\end{cases}
$$

which gives me : $x^2+2x-3=0 \quad\implies\quad  x=1,-3$

I assume I can only use $x=1$. plugging it back (into $x=y^2+z^2$) gives me the unit circle $1=y^2+z^2$. (So $r_{max}=1$ and $r_{min}=0$)

Now I can set-up my **x** values:

$x^2=3-2(y^2+z^2) \quad\overset{\text{polar}}{\implies}\quad x=+\sqrt{3-2r^2}$

$\mathrm{Flux}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{r^2}^{\sqrt{3-2r^2}}r^3\sin^2\theta \ dx\,dr\,d\theta$

Is the **integral set-up** and **thought process** right?

Answer (score 0):

Looks correct to me, the parameterization was done properly, the integrand is correct, the upper and lower bounds look correct. 
Nothing to worry about here.